# A custom clip to run while flex application loads itself

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

Whenever a swf is loaded a custom movie is shown (by default a rotating circle), is there some way where I can have my custom movie to play there. If you have any idea in this regard, then please help.

Thanks in advance.
Ashine.

Comment: example or some code are the least harmful things. Please show us some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a custom preloader.  [Here](http://www.flexer.info/2008/02/07/very-first-flex-preloader-customization/) is a very good example to get you started.